Why "incorrect password" alert never appears?
html code :
<div *ngIf="form.controls.password.errors?.['incorrect'] && form.controls.password.touched && !isFieldFocused('password')" class="alert2 alert-danger" role="alert">
              Incorrect password
</div>

typescript code :
async onSubmit(): Promise<void> {
    if (this.form.invalid) {
      this.markAllAsTouched();
      return;
    }
    const email = this.form.get('email')!.value;
    const userExists = await this.checkIfUserExists(email);
    this.isLoginInProgress.set(true);
    this.userExists = userExists;
    
    if (userExists) {
      (await this._authService.login(this.form.controls.email.value.trim(), this.form.controls.password.value.trim()))
        .pipe(
          catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
            if (error.error.code === 'auth/invalid-credential') {
              this.form.controls.password.setErrors({ incorrect: true });
            }
            this.handleAuthError(error);
            return of(error);
          }),
          tap(response => this._handleLogin(response)),
          finalize(() => this.isLoginInProgress.set(false))
        )
        .subscribe({
          error: (error) => {
            console.error('Login error:', error);
          }
        });
    } else {

      this.isLoginInProgress.set(false);
      this.authError.set(true); 
    }
  }

so after filling the login form ( email & password ) , I type an existing user with wrong password , in dev tools I get "Firebase: Error (auth/invalid-credential)" as an error but the "incorrect password" alert never appears

Have you test debug that those 3 conditions are returning true?

@Doug i think so

remove this condition "form.controls.password.errors?.['incorrect'] && form.controls.password.touched && !isFieldFocused('password')"
Reason: after you click on submit focus will be changed to submit button so, this condition form.controls.password.touched && !isFieldFocused('password') will fail.
instead : Make "Password" fields as required. Use only one condition where the password length is greater than zero and the password is incorrect then show incorrect password error message.

like that : <div *ngIf="form.controls.password.errors?.['incorrect'] && form.controls.password.value.length > 0" class="alert2 alert-danger" role="alert">
Incorrect password
 ?
